# Reducing parent-child class code duplication

Tags: c++, oop, parent-child

I'm having a problem with polymorphism and parent-child relationships. Take the following two classes, and imagine in my application I create an object of 'child'. Outside of the objects, the only function I call is update(), which in turn invokes everything else I need within the object. The only function in this sequence of calls that differs in 'parent' and 'child' is dosomething2().

```
class parent 
{
    public:
        void dosomething1() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething2
        void dosomething2() {};
        void update() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething1
}

class child : public parent
{
    void dosomething2() {}
}
```

I realized that if I create an object of 'child' and call update(), only the parent class functions will be called. I had to copy update() and dosomething1() to the child class, and then everything worked as expected. That's not a very nice solution though because there is a lot of duplicate code - is there a way to improve this?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to the answers provided, I updated the parent class with a virtual dosomething2() function. Now the correct function is invoked, and I don't have to copy dosomething1() to the child class. Unfortunately, if I do not copy update() to the child class, I get a symbol lookup error (both parent and child are in a library together).

```
class parent 
{
    public:
        void dosomething1() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething2
        virtual void dosomething2() {};
        void update() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething1
}

class child : public parent
{
    void dosomething2() {}
    /*void update() {}; //symbol lookup error if this is left uncommented */
}
```

**UPDATE2**
The symbol lookup error was not related to the code. I did a make clean, and then make (which builds a .so library and the executable) and now things work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use keyword `virtual` in parent-class if you want `dynamic-polymorphism`. And then reimplement or no reimplement virtual functions in child class.

```
class parent 
{
    public:
        void dosomething1() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething2
        virtual void dosomething2() {};
        void update() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething1
}
```

Comment: After introducing the virtual keyword I'm getting a symbol lookup error on update() (I didn't mention in the question that parent and child are in a library because I didn't think it makes a difference) - any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mark the functions in the base-class as virtual:

```
class parent 
{
    public:
        virtual void dosomething1() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething2
        virtual void dosomething2() {};
        void update() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething1
}
```

Also, FYI, what you're doing is called the [*template method pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: Does dosomething1() have to be virtual if it isn't redefined in the child class?

Comment: I'm getting a symbol lookup error on update() now (I didn't mention in the question that parent and child are in a library because I didn't think it makes a difference) - any idea why?

Comment: @akid it has to be virtual for polymorphism to work. The linker shouldn't complain if that's your code (implementation in the headers)

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference if I declare it virtual or not (functions declared in headers, defined in code files).

Comment: @akid are you linking the files together? Probably not.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I solved my problem. All answers were quite similar, so it was not easy to pick which one to accept.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the relevant functions `virtual`. Assuming you want `child`'s `doSomething1()` and `doSomething2()` to be called from a call to `update()`:

```
class parent 
{
    public:
        virtual void dosomething1() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething2
        virtual void dosomething2() {};
        void update() {}; //amongst other things, calls dosomething1
}

class child : public parent
{
    virtual void dosomething2() {}
}
```

Then, a call to a `child`'s `update()` will call the derived class' methods, if available. Note that `update() is not virtual, so you should have no filed called`update`in`child` or you will hide that name.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be in this example, but it could well be necessary in a real case.

Comment: In general, when using the template method pattern, you don't override the method that describes the algorithm.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know that, but OP didn't say anything about the template method. For all I know, they will end up hiding the `update` method too.

Comment: It's quite common to make it protected, yes.

Comment: Child doesn't have it's own doSomething1(). The sequence I'd like to have is parent:update()->parent:doSomething1()->child:doSomething2(). BTW, I got the parent class from someone else and am extending it with child. I agree with the 'protected' statement, that was on my to-do list once I get this working.

Comment: @akid I would say private would be even clearer. I don't see what can be gained from protected, unless you want to call the parent's one without overriding from the child.